# Make CalendarView in android with selection of specific dates from limited number

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I need to create `calendarview` in my android app (not a `dialog`, not a `datepicker dialog`) with dates selection. And i need to choose specific dates from limited number.

For example, i need to show calendar, where dates 11/11/2016 and 20/11/2016 (for example again) are enabled (with specific color) to select and all other are disabled (with specific color too).

Comment: CalendarView (standard android view) and MaterialCalendarView ( from https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview )